# Unity can't see my function in the event in image touch up event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I tried a simple program in unity this is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

 public class NewBehaviourScript1 : MonoBehaviour
 {
  // Start is called before the first frame update
   public void Setr()
  {
     Debug.Log("I am alive!");
  }

 }
```

and then I add object select the event drag my script and then I cant choose the `Setr` function

Comment: Please be more clear in your explainiation. Which component are you trying to use this on? Is this script attached to the same component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are trying to add this to some sort of OnClick() or other event. Make sure you add this script to a gameObject and drag the **gameobject** not the script into the event in the editor. From there you should be able to select your function.